# Unity axis issue. AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up) is moving my object on the Z axis instead of the Y axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, axis

I am following a tutorial of moving a rocket. (Vector3.up) pushes the object on the Z axis instead of the Y axis. When I do AddRelativeForce(0, 0, 1) it pushes the rocket up. almost like its reading XZY instead of XYZ. Are there any settings to adjust this I am new to unity

I was expecting Vector3.up to work on the Y axis. It ended up using the Z axis

Comment: Are you using a rocket model, and if so, is the model's rotations set correctly. ---- In the editor screen, click on your model like you would to move it, and take a look at the arrows. The Green arrow shows the Y axis. Is it facing up? If one of the other arrows is facing up (likely the blue z-axis from what you have explained), then you need to correct your models rotation. --- Also, checking your objects positions when the game is playing, to see what axis it is actually changing - sounds like it should be the Y axis, but it never hurts to check.

Comment: Rotating the model -90x in Blender and applying rotation is what worked. Something about exporting from blender to unity means that's necessary

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! I had the same problem before, and was troubling shooting for days before I realised lol. I will put my comment as the answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a rocket model, and if so, is the model's rotations set correctly.

In the editor screen, click on your model like you would to move it, and take a look at the arrows.

The Green arrow shows the Y axis. Is it facing up? If one of the other arrows is facing up (likely the blue z-axis from what you have explained), then you need to correct your models rotation.

Also, worth noting, when exporting, you will have options for the transform on the right side. Try to make sure it has "Forward:-z forward", and "Up: Y Up".

Happy Coding!